# Differential equation of guitar string frequency change

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to model the frequency loss of a guitar string over time due to the loss of tension in the guitar string. The algebraic equation of this is described as:
$f=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{T}{m/L}}}{2L}$

Where m and L are constants and T has a known initial value. Can anybody help me a bit further on how I go from this algebraic equation to a differential equation?

Best regards

Comment: What is the variable that changes?T?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If T is the variable that changes with time, then
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{mL}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt T}\frac{dT}{dt}. $$
Use the chain rule.

**EDIT** (as requested by the OP): Note that in $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{\frac{T}{m/L}}}{2L}$, $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{m/L}}}{2L}$ is a constant and has nothing to do with change. We know that differentiation has a linearity property, i.e. $$\frac{d}{dx}(ax)=a\frac{d}{dx}(x)$$ if a is constant. So we have
$$\frac{d}{dt} \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{\frac{T}{m/L}}}{2L}= \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{m/L}}}{2L} \frac{d}{dt}\sqrt T= \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{m/L}}}{2L} \frac{d}{dt}T^{\frac 12}  $$ Now, use

1. the formula $\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$ for any n,
2. The [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) $$= \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{m/L}}}{2L}\frac 12T^{ \frac
       12-1}\frac{dT}{dt}= \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{m/L}}}{2L}\frac 12T^{
       -\frac 12} \frac{dT}{dt}$$$$ = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{mL}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt T}\frac{dT}{dt} $$

Comment: Yes, T is the variable that changes with time. Sorry that I was unclear about that.

Comment: Is the answer clear ? @nofnof

Comment: Is 1/2sqrt(T) multiplied by T' at the end there?

Comment: Yes @nofnof that’s it.

Comment: Could you maybe tell me something about the steps in between?

Comment: I hope the edit helps. Feel free to post for any further query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't give you an upvote due to too little reputation